# HTML5 combine commonly-used attributes into super-attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a lot of buttons that look like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#qq" data-req="foo">Foo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#qq" data-req="bar">Bar</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#qq" data-req="baz">Baz</button>
```

I'd like to avoid so much repetition; is there any way to define some sort of single attribute that will expand to several other attributes? For example it might end up looking like

```
super x = 'type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#qq"';

<button super="x" data-req="foo">Foo</button>
<button super="x" data-req="bar">Bar</button>
<button super="x" data-req="baz">Baz</button>
```

NB. Of course this could be done with server-side scripting but I'm hoping to avoid that. I am using Bootstrap 3.3.4 , these buttons trigger a Bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<button type="button" class="x" data-req="foo">Foo</button>
<button type="button" class="x" data-req="bar">Baz</button>
<button type="button" class="x" data-req="baz">Baz</button>
```

and in the Javascript section

```
$("button.x").addClass("btn btn-info");
$("button.x").attr("data-toggle", "modal");
$("button.x").attr("data-target", "#qq");
```

This removes most of the repetition however I am still wondering if there is a more elegant and/or runtime-efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be looking for a client side view framework such as Handlebars or React.js. Where you can send (and cache) the templates on the client and then bind to JSON you retrieve from the server.

You could use a full stack framework such as Ember.js or Angular, but that is probably more than you need.

Comment: Thanks, Handlebars looks like it might be quite useful